# Laravel Eloquent 'with' and 'belongsTo' relationship returns null when there's related data in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having issue with Laravel's belongsTo and 'with' when querying data.
I have 2 models named Leave Type and Leave Application as below.

1) Leave Type

```
class LeaveType extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['id','company_id','category','renewal_month','no_of_days','status','deleted_at','created_at','updated_at','require_attachment',
                        'require_reason','employment_type_id','increment_flag','service_duration','increment_days','max_days','carry_forward_flag','carry_forward_value',
                        'expiry_duration','expiry_flag','advance_notice_required','other_names'];

    //hook into model and listen for any eloquent events
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(
            function ($model) {
                $model->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
                $model->company_id = auth()->user()->company_id;
            }
        );
    }

    public function leaveApplication()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\LeaveApplication','leave_type_id','id');
    }

}
```

2) Leave Application

```
class LeaveApplication extends Model
{
    const PENDING = '0';
    const APPROVED = '1';
    const REJECTED = '2';

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['id','company_id','user_id','ref_no','applied_date','from_date','to_date','days',
                        'half_day_flag','leave_type_id','reason','attachment','approved_status','approved_remark','approved_by','is_deducted',
                        'deleted_at','created_at','updated_at'];
    public $incrementing = false;

    //hook into model and listen for any eloquent events
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(
            function ($model) {
                $model->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
                $model->company_id = auth()->user()->company_id;
                $model->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            }
        );
    }

    public function leaveType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LeaveType','leave_type_id','id');
    }
}
```

But when i query the data from the table

```
$leaveApplication = LeaveApplication::with('leaveType:id,category')->get();
```

I got this result.

```
  {
        "id": "5be4af08-9983-4fad-b73d-56f651cd0355",
        "company_id": "5410e025-62b1-47db-a65b-8b5e25f6ed59",
        "user_id": "dee83d11-5761-4704-8884-cbaa605d9039",
        "ref_no": "L20191102",
        "applied_date": "2019-11-26",
        "from_date": "2019-11-26",
        "to_date": "2019-11-27",
        "days": 2,
        "half_day_flag": 0,
        "leave_type_id": "967d1834-061d-4773-b4c8-0d48fe568987",
        "reason": null,
        "attachment": "/tmp/phpdWQ5oR",
        "approved_status": 0,
        "approved_remark": null,
        "approved_by": null,
        "is_deducted": 0,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2019-11-26 01:37:44",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-26 01:37:44",
        "leave_type": {
            "id": "967d1834-061d-4773-b4c8-0d48fe568987",
            "category": "Annual"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "0305a9ae-4d2b-478d-abfc-bbad3030fdf1",
        "company_id": "5410e025-62b1-47db-a65b-8b5e25f6ed59",
        "user_id": "dee83d11-5761-4704-8884-cbaa605d9039",
        "ref_no": "L20191101",
        "applied_date": "2019-11-26",
        "from_date": "2019-11-26",
        "to_date": "2019-11-27",
        "days": 2,
        "half_day_flag": 0,
        "leave_type_id": "8e37b068-42ac-413e-b3f4-8d8c83aa1656",
        "reason": null,
        "attachment": "/tmp/phpFPsxmQ",
        "approved_status": 0,
        "approved_remark": null,
        "approved_by": null,
        "is_deducted": 0,
        "deleted_at": null,
        "created_at": "2019-11-26 01:36:04",
        "updated_at": "2019-11-26 01:36:04",
        "leave_type": null
    }
```

Both of the leave type id exist in the LeaveType table, but the second relationship keep showing null for the leave type. What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

the data for my LeaveType table is as below.

```
{
    "table": "leave_types",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "id": "8e37b068-42ac-413e-b3f4-8d8c83aa1656",
            "company_id": "5410e025-62b1-47db-a65b-8b5e25f6ed59",
            "category": "Paternity",
            "renewal_month": 1,
            "no_of_days": 7,
            "status": 1,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "require_attachment": 1,
            "require_reason": 0,
            "employment_type_id": 1,
            "increment_flag": 0,
            "service_duration": 0,
            "increment_days": 0,
            "max_days": 0,
            "carry_forward_flag": 0,
            "carry_forward_value": 1,
            "expiry_duration": 12,
            "expiry_flag": 0,
            "advance_notice_required": 0,
            "other_names": null
        },
        {
            "id": "967d1834-061d-4773-b4c8-0d48fe568987",
            "company_id": "5410e025-62b1-47db-a65b-8b5e25f6ed59",
            "category": "Annual",
            "renewal_month": 1,
            "no_of_days": 14,
            "status": 1,
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "require_attachment": 0,
            "require_reason": 0,
            "employment_type_id": 1,
            "increment_flag": 0,
            "service_duration": 0,
            "increment_days": 0,
            "max_days": 0,
            "carry_forward_flag": 0,
            "carry_forward_value": 1,
            "expiry_duration": 12,
            "expiry_flag": 0,
            "advance_notice_required": 0,
            "other_names": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is category in your with

Comment: @Poldo i updated my model with the fillable so that the table fields can be seen. My category is suppose to return a string like Training or Sick Leave.

Comment: @Poldo i have already updated the data for the second leave type

Comment: try using this line return $this->belongsTo('App\LeaveType','leave_type_id');

Comment: @Poldo it's the same as well, still getting null

Answer (score 0):

In your model declare which table you're using.

```
class LeaveType extends Model
{ ...
  protected $table = "leave_type";

    public function leaveApplication()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\LeaveApplication','leave_type_id');
    }



class LeaveApplication extends Model
    { ...
      protected $table = "leave_application ";

     public function leaveType()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\LeaveType','leave_type_id');
     }
```